# awk line processing $NF

Tags: awk

I have a problem with awk processing simple thing.
But not simple and clear for me.
This is what I need to parse:

```
$ cat file
/dir1/dir11/file1
/dir10/dir103/file2
/dir2/dir21/dir221/file3
```

And what is desired for me, to have separated path to files (without file names), like:

```
/dir1/dir11
/dir10/dir103
/dir2/dir21/dir221
```

I have allready tried this:

```
$ cat file | awk -F"/" '{for (i=1;i<NF;i++) print $i}'

dir1
dir11

dir10
dir103

dir2
dir21
dir221
```

and this:

```
$ cat file | awk -F"/" '{for (i=1;i<NF;i++) printf $i}'
dir1dir11dir10dir103dir2dir21dir221
```

and best results :

```
$ cat file | awk -F"/" '{ $NF=""; print}'
dir1 dir11
dir10 dir103
dir2 dir21 dir221
```

But still missing `/` within path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This awk should work:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"} {$NF=""}'1 file
```

Comment: Thank you, all. :) I'm just curious, when I want change OFS to "\" how can it be in this example?

Comment: @molni: You want to use backslash as OFS or forward slash? Your example above shows forward slash only.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the output field separator if you modify the record. I would just decrement the number of fields if you have `GNU awk`:

```
$ awk '{NF--}1' FS='/' OFS='/' file
/dir1/dir11
/dir10/dir103
/dir2/dir21/dir221
```

Else just add `OFS='/'` to your last command:

```
$ awk '{$NF=""}1' FS='/' OFS='/' file
```

Or with a simple substitution using `sed`:

```
$ sed 's%/[^/]*$%%' file
/dir1/dir11
/dir10/dir103
/dir2/dir21/dir221
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way with `awk`:

```
awk '{sub(/\/[^/]+$/,"")}1' file
```

**Output:**

```
$ cat file
/dir1/dir11/file1
/dir10/dir103/file2
/dir2/dir21/dir221/file3
$ awk '{sub(/\/[^/]+$/,"")}1' file
/dir1/dir11
/dir10/dir103
/dir2/dir21/dir221
```